# Rotate camera around object for animation

Tags: animation

I would like to get the camera to slowly rotate around a object and keep facing it. I would to this with key frames but then the camera would travel in strait paths. How could I do this?

Comment: Or [How do I 'pan' the camera around an axis for an animation?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-do-i-pan-the-camera-around-an-axis-for-an-animation?)