# Rotation animation isn't fixed on the pivot point

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate a door turning and I've successfully created the keyframes by using rotate on the X-Y axis around my 3D cursor. I've created start and end keyframes that are fine:
[image]

[image]

note how both have the end fixed on the 3d cursor, my pivot point. However, the animation has the door poking out, for lack of a better word, 'escaping' the hinge.

[image]

It rotates and changes location, making it jut out and snap back again.
I've tried adding more keyframes in the middle to fix its position, but then I can't control the easing...

I'm very new to blender and animation, so I'm not sure how to proceed ><
Is there a setting to sort of 'fix' the door to the 'hinge' or pivot point during animation? Any help would be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you animate, it doesn't take the 3D Cursor into account anymore, it will rotate around the object origin, or around the bone to which your object will be parented (or empty as suggested by Nicola Sap). So if you want your door hinge as a pivot point, you need to change the door origin and put it on its hinge: in *Edit* mode, select a hinge vertex, press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then back in *Object* mode, press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor* (for 2.8: Header menu > *Object* > *Set Origin* > *Origin to 3D Cursor*). Then create your animation, your door should pivote around its hinge.

Comment: Well, what is the short cut for version 2.8 ?

Comment: for 2.8: Header menu > *Object* > *Set Origin* > *Origin to 3D Cursor*

Answer (score 4):

You can either change the pivot point as [moonboots suggests](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127155/16395), or (if you need the pivot point to stay elsewhere for other reasons) you can

1. Add an *Empty* on the desired axis of rotation

   [image]
2. Select the door, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Select the *Empty*, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *Set Parent to Object*
3. Animate the *Empty*, not the door

   [image]

(this is a very common procedure for [rotating a camera around a scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133/16395) by using an *Empty*)