# Auto turntable animation

Tags: python, scripting

First, I tried to do my first turning table with Blender that I do not master through tutorials and eventually I succeed. I regret that I cannot make the "same turntable" for each models in my files to see easily what model looks like.
Then I tried to find an easier way so I explored 2 things:
-An Add on that I understood lately it is not compatible with my Blender version (2.8.2).
It's available on github : https://github.com/ChestMimic/blender-automatic-turntable

I tried to update sources to make it work but it didn't and I cannot debug this code because I don't have the skills to understand how it works.
Perhaps I should install an old Blender, most probably a 2.7. something but I can't get which version would be compatible with that plugin. BtW most of the interface changed between 2.7 and 2.8 right? So disturbing

-I tried an add on bundled with Blender called "Animation: Turnaround Camera" which is doing part of what I am looking for. I also face another issue, some STL loaded are not centered I do not even know why!

I also found this really interesting topic : [Add camera at random position through Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176296/add-camera-at-random-position-through-python)
This script on the bottom seems to create the turntable but the script doesn't care about the size of the STL imported, it's position, ...
I can understand a little of Python but all related to 3D and mathematics for it (translation of matrix, ... is quite unusual for me.

Can someone would be able to give some guidance for a noob on Blender to do what I'm trying to do?
I would like to do a script that make automatically a turntable video as mp4, avi, mov (ideally without background) on STL files whatever and then I will need to convert that video to a gif

I would like to script it to always have the "same result" and also because I have too much STL to do proceed with a manual way.

Thanks a lot for any comment!

Comment: blender comes with a bundled turnaround camera script

Comment: is it fine if it does not involve a script? Try watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghCsEVj2CFE

Comment: I really need a script to run it on 100+ STL's therefore bundled or any manual steps that make any difference is not possible.