# How to rotate the camera around an object and then zoom?

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

I followed [this approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-do-i-pan-the-camera-around-an-axis-for-an-animation) for animating the camera around an object.

**Once the rotation is done, how to zoom or translate the camera toward another location on the scene ?**

I did not find any easy way since the camera is linked to the empty frame.

Is it possible to change its relations and constraints using key-frames ?

Maybe it is better to create another camera, but I don't know how to place it with the exact same position and rotation as the first one (at the end of its rotation)...

Comment: May find this of some help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176762/15543   Try running the scripts on the default file.

Comment: you can either parent the camera to an empty and move the empty, or give the camera a Track To constraint and change the Influence values of the constraint?